# ¿Como mostrar todo el contenido de una tabla de Mysql en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Quiero lograr que las personas con el rol de lector, solo vean los contenido de sus filas, pero que el administrador los vea todo, estoy usando este código pero no entiendo por que no funciona. No veo donde esta el fallo aquí en la lógica, ya que cuando quiero mostrar todas las tablas uso $consulta2 que selecciona todo de usuario

```html
<?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';


 $id_sesion = $_SESSION['id'];
 $consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_sesion . "'" );
 $consulta2 = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario" );
 

 

 // error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ----->  
 // se arreglo viendo el error asi 'if (!$consulta){ echo mysqli_error ($conn);}' resulta que escribi mal la tabla, usarlo para ver mas errores


 // https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp
 // mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);
 // https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ 

 if ((mysqli_num_rows ($consulta)> 0) || $_SESSION['cargo'] = "lector")
  //  mysqli_num_rows ($consulta) va a ser igual  al numero de columnas, de la misma manera que  "Mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuarios")"  sera igual al valor que lleva dentro del parentesis. Por lo que si es mayor a 0, osea si hay columnas en la consulta, viendo asi que fue satisfactoria, se hace lo siguiente.

//array es fila (<-- -->), no columna 
 {

  echo "<p> <br>"; // <------ sin esto no se muestra nada de los echos de abajo


  // mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);
  // [result ]= Mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result()
  // [resulttype ] = MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM, MYSQLI_BOTH
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)  )
   // otro error: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_ASSOC - assumed 'MYSQL_ASSOC'
   // use esto "if (!$row){ echo mysqli_error ($MYSQLI_ASSOC);}" resulta que coloque MYSQL_ASOC, cuando tuvo que ser MYSQLI_ASSOC
   // https://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/9199/thread/4/

   {

   //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970936/how-to-echo-out-table-rows-from-the-db-php#
   echo "<tr>";

   echo "
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Nombre </th>
      <th>Fecha creacion </th>
      <th>Nick </th>
      <th>Telefono </th>
      

    </thead>
   ";

   echo " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
   echo "</tr></table>";



  }



 }

else if ((mysqli_num_rows ($consulta2)> 0) || $_SESSION['cargo'] = 'admin')

{
 echo "<p> <br>";

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)  )
   {
   echo "<tr>";

   echo "
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Nombre </th>
      <th>Fecha creacion </th>
      <th>Nick </th>
      <th>Telefono </th>
      

    </thead>
   ";

   echo " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
   echo " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
   echo "</tr></table>";



  }
}



//Se te está pasando regresar $respuesta en formato JSON y su encabezado
header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

Anexo unas imágenes mostrando como sin importar su cargo, siguen mostrando lo mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDIT PARA ANEXOS** imagen de como luce ahora al sustituir el "else if" por "if" y del backend encargado de crear **$_SESSION['cargo']** por que parece que allí esta el problema, no parece reconocerlo, no se si cometí un error allí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conexion.php';
//Declaramos un arreglo que será nuestro retorno
$respuesta = array();

//Primero hay que validar que las variables existan
//La superglobal $_REQUEST responde a los verbos GET y POST
if( empty( $_REQUEST['pwd'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['nick'] ) ){
  $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Usuario y/o password vacío';
}


else{
  //Guardamos y limpiamos las variables
  $pwd= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['pwd']);
  $nick= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST ['nick']);

  //Creamos el SQL, no siempre funciona agregando así las variables, yo recomiendo concatenar
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE nick = '". $nick. "' AND password = '".$pwd ."'"; 

  //Validamos que la consulta esté bien hecha

  $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows ($result)> 0)
    //  mysqli_num_rows ($result) va a ser igual  al numero de columnas, de la misma manera que  "Mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuarios")"  sera igual al valor que lleva dentro del parentesis. Por lo que si es mayor a 0, osea si hay columnas en la consulta, viendo asi que fue satisfactoria, se hace lo siguiente.
{
          //Aquí asignamos nuestro arreglo, assoc o array te sirven
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );

      //creas tus variables de sesión
      $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['nick'] = $row['nick'];
      $_SESSION['cargo'] = $row['cargo'];
      $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Se crearon las variables de sesión, conexión exitosa';

      //Recuerda que por limpieza del servidor, borramos la información de la query y cerramos conexión
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      mysqli_close( $conn );

}

  else{
      $respuesta['mensaje'] = 'Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta';

  }

}

//Ahora si, retornamos nuestra respuesta con formato y encabezado JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Tema solucionado. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ahi te deje un codigo, en base a lo que necesitas explicado, espero me entiendas, y te recomiendo el uso de sentencias preparadas, la cual evita la injeccion de sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leyendo el codigo hay dos probelmas principales:

1. De logica en el cual primero debes preguntar que tipo de cargo
   tiene, para que no ejecutes las 2 sentencias siempre, solo debes
   ejecutar la que necesitas y si la condicion se cumple.
2. A cada vuelta de ciclo creabas la misma tabla con la mismca cabecera, por ende siempre te iba a imprimir la ultima fila.

dicho lo anterior, tu codigo deberia quedar asi:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conexion.php';

//creas una variable con el contenido base de la tabla

$tabla = "
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nombre </th>
            <th>Fecha creacion </th>
            <th>Nick </th>
            <th>Telefono </th>
    </thead>
      ";

//pregunta primero que tipo de usuario es 
if ($_SESSION['cargo'] == "lector") {
  //como es un lector necesitaras el id
  $id_sesion = $_SESSION['id'];
  //ejecutas la sentencia sql
  $consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_sesion . "'" );
  //preguntas si trajo resultados
  if ( $consulta->num_rows > 0)
  {


    //rescorres los resultados que haya traido
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) )
    {
      //como ya tenemos la base de la tabla aqui le sumamos las filas
      $tabla.= "</tr>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
      $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
      $tabla.= "</tr>";
    }
  }

}
else if ($_SESSION['cargo'] == 'admin'){
  //como es un aministrador no necesitamos id
  $consulta2 = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Usuario" );
  //preguntamos si trae registros
  if($consulta2->num_rows > 0){

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta2))
      {
        //sumamos las filas que trae
        $tabla.= "</tr>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['fecha_creacion']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['nick']."</td>";
        $tabla.= " <td>".$row['telefono']."</td>";
        $tabla.= "</tr>";
      }
  }
}

//aqui cierras la tabla
$tabla.= "</table>";
//la imprimes
echo $tabla;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

**EDICION**. habia un parentesis de mas y faltabala el `echo`

espero te sirva, me cuentas...

Comment: Obtengo un `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/html/crud_agenda/back_index.php on line 35`  en estas lineas de codigo `$tabla . = " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";` disculpa la demora,  estaba investigando de varias cosas que desconozco su funcionamiento y usaste en el código.

Comment: No te preocupe, asi es que se debe hacer, investigar el por que de las cosas, y respecto al error era que habia un parentesis de mas y faltabala el `echo`

Comment: El error continua en la misma linea `$tabla . = " <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>";` del  paréntesis de mas si me habia dado cuenta, pero del echo del final no, editado, aunque persiste el problema. Quizas esa syntaxis es de una version diferente de mi php o algo?  no veo por que no podria reconocerlo. Y gracias por el apoyo :)

Comment: Pasemos a un [(/https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82479/srjj-ayudas)]  para no hacer mas extenso aqui

Answer (score 0):

La primera consulta

```
 "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id = '". $id_sesion . "'"
```

es incorrecta porque el campo `id` es numerico (o al menos, así deberia ser si es la llave primaria y usaste las reglas de normalización), no debe ser tratado como una cadena. Debe ser así:

```
"SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id=". $id_sesion
```

aunque esta consulta solo te devolvera un resultado porque si el `id` el la llave primaria esta nunca se repite, por lo tanto solo puede tener un valor (o ninguno)

La segunda consulta es correcta, te devolverá todos los resultado pero, como está en un `else if` es probable que no entre en esa condición. Lo recomendables es sustituir el `else if` por un `if`.

Comment: Como que tipo de cadena? desconozco que la primera linea es un tipo de cadena de algún tipo y sus repercusiones, y me gustaría investigar al respecto. Ahora sobre la segunda consulta, decidí sustituirlo el `else if` por un `if` sin embargo ahora se ejecuta y muestra tanto la primera condicion osea la fila del id del usuario logeado...como la segunda condicion, osea tambien muestra todas las filas de la tabla. Y se ve en el index de cualquiera que inicie sesion sin importar su cargo, edite el post principal con unos anexos para explicar mejor mi punto

Comment: El problema no radica tanto en la sentencia, ya que veo que si le trae resultados, el problema es de logica y como lo recorres

Comment: cada campo de la tabla tiene un tipo de dato (varchar, text, int. etc), y supongo que el id es un int, pero en la consulta lo pones como si fuera un string. Ejemplo: no es lo mismo **SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id=1**  que **SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE id='1'** porque le pones comillas, como si fuera una cadena. Y eso es justo lo que haces

Comment: Pero si para traer todo como el quiere no necesita **WHERE**  y segundo, como el lo esta haciendo si le trae resultados